# Update batch file version

Tags: batch-file, version

Let's say I have a batch file called `somefile_old.bat`. Online there is a new version called `somefile_new.bat`. How do I check if there is a new version online from `somefile_old.bat`, and if there is, download it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Put a [hash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-1) of somefile_new.bat
   somewhere.
2. Calculate the hash of somefile_old.bat.
3. Compare the two.
4. If they're not the same, then download the new version and deal with
   the old one.

Comment: Thanks @npocmaka, not being on Windows, I don't know cmd.exe commands.

Answer (score 1):

with pure batch you can check if the version is newer only after you donload the file  and compare both (you can use [bitsadmin](http://ss64.com/nt/bitsadmin.html) or beter [wget](http://users.ugent.be/~bpuype/wget/) ) . As it is a batch file it will no take long time and will be may be the fastest way..

Comment: How would you use wget in batch?

Comment: download it with bitsadmin :-D